# Parsing osmChange files with Pyosmium

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmium

I'm trying to use Pyosmium to parse changesets from an osmChange file (to replicate the osmium changeset-filter [1] functionalities):

> > > class MyHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
> > >       ...     def changeset(self,changeset):
> > >       ...             print changeset
> > >
> > > handler = MyHandler()
> > >       handler.apply_file('mychange.xml>')

but nothing happens. No errors, no outputs.

I've tried to setup the osmium.io.Reader manually, and setting the entity bit:

> > > reader = osmium.io.Reader('mychange.xml',osmium.osm.osm_entity_bits.CHANGESET)
> > >       omsium.apply(reader,handler)

No output again.

Is it possible to parse osmChanges with Pyosmium? If yes, what's the right way to do it?

[1] http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#working-with-changesets

Comment: This question was also posted on the OSM dev list: https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2017-March/029784.html - please follow up there.

Comment: Thanks mmd, I'm not receiving the updates from the dev list. I just received a response saying that it was going to be moderated... I will follow the thread through the archive.